# Socket undeclared when i use -std=c99 [c]

Tags: c, sockets

I am actually work on a Socket project in C language.
I have just a little question: Why can't I use Socket when I use the flag "-std=c99" ?
When I compile my project without this flag I don't have any problem. I search some solution in Google but i didn't found any clue ...

Here is my code :

```
#if defined (WIN32)
#include <winsock2.h>
typedef int socklen;
#elif defined (linux)
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define closesocket(s) close(s)
typedef int SOCKET;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;
typedef struct sockaddr SOCKADDR;
#endif

#define PORT 1520
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int  main()
{
#if defined (WIN32)
  WSADATA WSAData;
  int error = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData);
#else
  int error = 0;
#endif

  SOCKET sock;
  SOCKADDR_IN sin;

  if (!error) {
    /* Socket Creation */
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* Connexion Configuration */
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // IP
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET; // Family
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT); // Port

    /* Connection to the socket */
    connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
      printf("Connexion to %s on the port %d\n", inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr), htons(sin.sin_port));
      send(sock, "MESSAGE RECEIVED!", sizeof(char) * 4095, 0);

    closesocket(sock);

#if defined (WIN32)
    WSACleanup();
#endif
  return 0;
  }
```

Here is my compilation message when I use -std=c99 :

```
client.c: In function ‘main’:
client.c:31:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘SOCKET’
client.c:32:3: erreur: unknown type name ‘SOCKADDR_IN’
client.c:36:5: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘socket’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:36:23: erreur: ‘AF_INET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
client.c:36:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
client.c:36:32: erreur: ‘SOCK_STREAM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
client.c:39:8: erreur: request for member ‘sin_addr’ in something not a structure or union
client.c:39:5: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘inet_addr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:40:8: erreur: request for member ‘sin_family’ in something not a structure or union
client.c:41:8: erreur: request for member ‘sin_port’ in something not a structure or union
client.c:41:5: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘htons’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:44:5: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘connect’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:44:20: erreur: ‘SOCKADDR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
client.c:44:30: erreur: expected expression before ‘)’ token
client.c:45:7: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘inet_ntoa’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:45:63: erreur: request for member ‘sin_addr’ in something not a structure or union
client.c:45:84: erreur: request for member ‘sin_port’ in something not a structure or union
client.c:46:7: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘send’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
client.c:48:5: attention : implicit declaration of function ‘closesocket’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Thank you.
PS: Sorry for my english!

Comment: Can you please write the compilation error

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete and unedited error log.

Comment: By the way, you're sending a lot of trash data. Anything beyond the strings terminator is off limits. You should also check for errors.

Comment: Like I said before, I didn't any problem whithout the flags. When i use -std=c99, seem's like that my compilator don't recognize any Socket function !

Comment: Apparently the prerocessor symbol `linux` is not defined when you specify a C standard. Use `#if defined(__linux__)` instead to check for Linux to include the socket headers.

Comment: If you're on WIN32 then SOCKET won't be `typedef`ed, hence the first error

Comment: Try `-std=gnu99`. ANSI C99 does not have some defines that may be necessary to include the proper typedefs.

Comment: Thanks M Oehm ! I use `(__linux__)` instead of `(linux)` and that work !

Comment: @Sergey, thank's, my project work without modifying my code with you include!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-std=gnu99`. ANSI C99 does not have some defines that are necessary to include the proper typedefs.