# What happens when I add the flag "-std=c99" to minwg32?

Tags: c, c99

On Windows with Code::Block with version 16.01, and with minwg32 gcc.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS)
#define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  11644473600000000Ui64
#else
#define DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS  11644473600000000ULL
#endif
#endif

struct timezone_ex
{
    int  tz_minuteswest; /* minutes W of Greenwich */
    int  tz_dsttime;     /* type of dst correction */
};

int gettimeofday_ex(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone_ex *tz);

/********************************************//**
 * \brief
 *
 * \param tv struct timeval*
 * \param tz struct timezone*
 * \return int
 *
 ***********************************************/
int gettimeofday_ex(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone_ex *tz)
{
    FILETIME ft;
    unsigned long long tmpres = 0;
    static int tzflag;

    if (tv)
    {
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);

        tmpres |= ft.dwHighDateTime;
        tmpres <<= 32;
        tmpres |= ft.dwLowDateTime;

        /*converting file time to unix epoch*/
        tmpres /= 10;  /*convert into microseconds*/
        tmpres -= DELTA_EPOCH_IN_MICROSECS;
        tv->tv_sec = (long)(tmpres / 1000000UL);
        tv->tv_usec = (long)(tmpres % 1000000UL);
    }
    if (tz)
    {
        if (!tzflag)
        {
            _tzset();
            tzflag++;
        }
        tz->tz_minuteswest = _timezone / 60;
        tz->tz_dsttime = _daylight;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct timeval t;

    gettimeofday_ex(&t, NULL);

    printf("t.tv_sec=%d, t.tz_dsttime=%d;\r\n", t.tv_sec, t.tv_usec);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code without the flag -std=c99, it's works;
Here is the build log:

> -------------- Build: Debug in TestForStudy (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-gcc.exe -g  -c D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c -o
>   obj\Debug\main.o mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestForStudy.exe
>   obj\Debug\main.o  -lpthread   Output file is
>   bin\Debug\TestForStudy.exe with size 40.23 KB Process terminated with
>   status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0
>   minute(s), 0 second(s))

But, if I add the flag -std=c99, and rebuild it again, I get the error message:

> -------------- Build: Debug in TestForStudy (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-gcc.exe -std=c99 -g  -c
>   D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\TestForStudy.exe obj\Debug\main.o 
>   -lpthread   D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c: In function 'gettimeofday_ex': D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c:60:13:
>   warning: implicit declaration of function '_tzset'
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                _tzset();
>                ^ D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c:63:30: error: '_timezone' undeclared (first use in this function)
>            tz->tz_minuteswest = _timezone / 60;
>                                 ^ D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c:63:30: note: each undeclared
>   identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
>   D:\WorkSpace\iSource\TestForStudy\main.c:64:26: error: '_daylight'
>   undeclared (first use in this function)
>            tz->tz_dsttime = _daylight;
>                             ^ Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0
>   second(s))

I have googled some things about this problem, and I have get nothing useful. And I don'w know if something wrong with my code or it's a bug with the minwg32?

Anyone can give me any hint for this problem? 
And thanks!

### Edit:

After I post this question, I read this question: 
[Socket undeclared when i use -std=c99 [c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516455/socket-undeclared-when-i-use-std-c99-c)

It seems like the same problem, and I try to change the -std=c99 to -std=gnu99， it works again.

So, is this a bug in minwg32 with the flag c99? Because I think no mater with which flag, the code don't have any error, all the flags shouldn't have errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a specific C standard version in the command line, all non-standard content of standard header files gets "hidden". This is what happened to `tzset`. It is declared in `<time.h>`, but it is not a standard member of `<time.h>`. Standard library does not have such function.

If you want your compiler to see it in `<time.h>` and use it, specify `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99`. If you want your program to be standard-compliant, use `-std=c99` and forget about `tzset`. Either this or that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to AnT's answer: There are *different* extensions to the C standard library, some are specified in POSIX, some are BSD extensions some come from *System V* Unix and of course there are GNU specific extensions, to name only a few.

I personally suggest to always compile with the `-std` flag set to one of the ISO C standards, preferably the latest (`-std=c11`). Then, if you need to use extensions, define the [feature test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) enabling them before you `#include` any standard headers only for the files that need them, e.g. in a file using `POSIX.1-2001` functions, use this very first line:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
```

The reason for this recommendation is to make it explicit *where* and *which* extensions to the language are used. This simplifies porting to a different platform later. It also encourages you to separate code dependent on extenstions clearly from fully portable code.